# jQuery Validate stop form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate to the form, but when the form is validated it reloads or submits the page I want to stop that action. I already use the event.preventDefault(), but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
$("#step1form").validate();
$("#step1form").on("submit", function(e){
    var isValid = $("#step1form").valid();

    if(isValid){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Things i would like to do after validation
        $(".first_step_form").fadeOut();
        if(counter == 3){
            $(".second_step_summary").fadeIn();
            $(".third_step_form").fadeIn();
            $(".third_inactive").fadeOut();
        }else if(counter < 3){
            $(".second_step_form").fadeIn();
            $(".third_inactive").fadeIn();
        }

        $(".first_step_summary").fadeIn();
        $(".second_inactive").fadeOut();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: You've got `e.preventDefault()` in the wrong place.  It's inside the `if` statement that only runs when the form is valid.

Comment: It will if the form's valid, but it's in the wrong place regardless.

Comment: `return true;` in `if(isValid)` block

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `submitHandler` is a callback function built into the plugin.

> `submitHandler` (default: native form submit):
>
> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated.

Since the `submitHandler` automatically captures the click of the submit button and only fires on a valid form, you do not need another submit handler, nor do you need to use `valid()` to test the form.

You code can be replaced with:

```
$("#step1form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // Things I would like to do after validation
        $(".first_step_form").fadeOut();
        if(counter == 3){
            $(".second_step_summary").fadeIn();
            $(".third_step_form").fadeIn();
            $(".third_inactive").fadeOut();
        }else if(counter < 3){
            $(".second_step_form").fadeIn();
            $(".third_inactive").fadeIn();
        }
        $(".first_step_summary").fadeIn();
        $(".second_inactive").fadeOut();
        return false;  // block the default submit action
    }
});
```

Comment: where to specify the action url to submit ?

Comment: @coding_idiot,  since he wants to use `preventDefault()` it's assumed the OP is doing an Ajax submission inside the `submitHandler`. Without a `submitHandler` function, the default `action` on the `<form>` element will fire.

Comment: thanks, it works. But unfortunately, I have input fields with `dot` in name. Please see my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219923/how-to-validate-input-fields-with-a-dot-in-name-using-the-jquery-validation-plug/20220457?noredirect=1#20220457

Comment: @coding_idiot, you are not supposed to highjack comments like this.  And somebody already posted the correct answer to your question.

Comment: it wasn't there, when I commented here. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 8):

I use this basic structure for all my JS validation, which does what your asking

```
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
    // check validation
    if (some_value != "valid") {
        return false;
    }
});
```

You don't need `e.preventDefault();` and a `return false;` statement, they do the same thing.

Comment: Not exactly. `return false` within a jQuery event handler = `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 1):

The plugin provides callbacks for valid and invalid form submission attempts.  If you provide a submitHandler callback then the form doesn't get submitted to the server automatically.

```
$("#step1form").validate({
   submitHandler : function()
   {
        // the form is valid 
        $(".first_step_form").fadeOut();
        if(counter == 3){
            $(".second_step_summary").fadeIn();
            // etc
        }
   }
});
```