# How to validate input fields with a dot in name using the jquery validation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, jquery-validate

I'm using [this jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
<s:textfield cssClass="form-control input-default" name="contest.title" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title"
                             />
```

Validation doesn't work for this, but if I change the name to `title` - validation works.

I tried searching, but couldn't find a means to validate fields with a `.` in their name.

Please help

**Update**

*Script*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("#contestform").validate({
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
//                        return false;  // block the default submit action
                    },
                    rules: {
                        title: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        link: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        startdt: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        enddt: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        descr: {
                            required: true
                        },
                    },
                    messages: {
                        title: "Please enter a title",
                        link: "Please enter the sponser redirection link",
                        startdt: "Please select start date",
                        enddt: "Please select end date",
                        descr: "Please enter description"
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

*Part of the form*

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="contestform">
            <s:hidden name="option" value="option"/>
            <s:hidden name="contest.idcontest"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <s:textfield cssClass="form-control input-default" name="contest.title" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title"
                             />
            </div>
```

Comment: You need to add code samples of the jQuery you are using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to put the field names in qoutes. From the [plugin documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

> Fields with complex names (brackets, dots)
>
> When you have a name attribute like user[name], make sure to put the
>   name in quotes. More details in the [General Guidelines](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference).

The sample in the linked reference:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    // no quoting necessary
    name: "required",
    // quoting necessary!
    "user[email]": "email",
    // dots need quoting, too!
    "user.address.street": "required"
  }
});
```