# jquery unobtrusive stops working if asp-for has dots in name

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'm using asp.net core with mvc 6 and jquery-validation-unobtrusive js library. The thing is unobtrusive js library doesn't check my input when i submit my form.

everething is pretty simple, here's basic example:

works:

```
@model MyModel
...
<input asp-for="MyField" placeholder="...">
<span asp-validation-for="MyField"></span>
```

MyModel contains only my models properties.

exmple:

```
public class MyModel
{ 
 public string MyField
 public string MyField2
 ...
}
```

not working:

```
@model VM
...
<input asp-for="MyModel.MyField" placeholder="...">
<span asp-validation-for="MyModel.MyField"></span>
```

VM contains MyModel class plus other properties.

exmple:

```
public class VM
{ 
 public MyModel MyModel
 public CustomClass OtherClass
 ...
}
```

Why it doesn't show validation errors?

Comment: I guess you're referring to MVC Core?

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzetti84 exactly, i just fixed from "MVC 5" to "MVC 6". my bad.

Comment: i just tested this is mvc6 and it seems to work fine.. i just altered the default template's register page and put the registermodel inside another class and the validation works when i use `<span asp-validation-for="RegisterModel.Email" class="text-danger"></span>`

Comment: do you have the correct versions of jquery validation and jquery validate unobtrusive?

Comment: Do you have a model `class VM` with property named `MyModel` that in turn contains a property named `MyField`? (the code in your first snippet suggest `VM` is the assembly name)

Comment: @JamieD77 yeah, i'm using the last one. jquery.validate 1.14 and jquery.validation.unobtrusive 3.2.6. all works fine when i'm not using dots in names.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you're right it was incorrect pseudo code. i fixed my topic.

Comment: And is the code in your classes correct? (all you have shown is fields, not properties (no `{ get; set' }`), and fields are not validated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:
https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/issues/39#issuecomment-237945087

@rok7

> While trying to provide an application for investigation I found the
>   problem: When a new ASP.Net Core application is created everything
>   works ok. However, if in VisualStudio the file bower.json is manually
>   modified (because jquery-validation-unobtrusive is not listed by the
>   ‘Browse’ function, it's necessary for example to select a different
>   version), then VisualStudio restores jquery-validation-unobtrusive
>   with the following difference to the original file : Original:
>
> ```
> function escapeAttributeValue(value) {
>
>     // As mentioned on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
>
>     return value.replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~])/g, "\\$1");
> } VisualStudio-restored
>
> function escapeAttributeValue(value) {
>
>     // As mentioned on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
>
>     return value.replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~])/g, "\\\\$1");
> } These magically inserted ‘\’ caused my problems!!!
> ```

@ryanbrandenburg

> Those \ were the result of an attempt to fix a different issue, but
>   upon closer inspection that issue was caused by something else and we
>   can revert that change. That's happening in #44.

Shortly a workaround of this situation would be a manual fixing the mentioned line or a downgrading to 3.2.5 version.

I believe it will be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

someone had the same problem before and answered well.

> You need to put the field names in qoutes. When you have a name attribute like user[name], make sure to put the name in quotes

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    // no quoting necessary
    name: "required",
    // quoting necessary!
    "user[email]": "email",
    // dots need quoting, too!
    "user.address.street": "required"
  }
});
```

Look at this for more info [Validate input fields with a dot in name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20220457/1766014)

hope this helps :)

Comment: well, this is close. but i'm applying unobtrusive library with mvc tag-helpers.