# Jquery Validation fields with dot in asp-for

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

validation is not working here, please guide me. I tried to follow this but didn;t work [How to validate input fields with a dot in name using the jquery validation plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219923/how-to-validate-input-fields-with-a-dot-in-name-using-the-jquery-validation-plug) thanks

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/arshad7abdul/8mu8wL84/4/

```
 <form id="appForm" asp-controller="some" asp-action="AnonymousApp" method="post">

<div class="panel-body pt0 p10">
            <section class="grid grid--direction-row">
                <!-- First Name -->
                <div class="grid__col-4">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                    <input asp-for="TaxPreparer.FirstName" class="form-control" maxlength="50"/>
                </div>

                <!-- Middle Name -->
                <div class="grid__col-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Middle Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="TaxPreparer.MiddleName" class="form-control charlimit" maxlength="50"/>
                </div>

                <!-- Last Name -->
                <div class="grid__col-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Last Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                    <input asp-for="TaxPreparer.LastName" class="form-control charlimit" maxlength="50"/>
                </div>
            </section>

 </div>
 <input class="btn btn-success btn-large" style="float: right; "id="submitApp" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var checkformValidation = function () {
            $("#appForm").validate({
            rules: {
                "TaxPreparer.FirstName": "required"
            }
            });
        }

   $('#submitApp').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            checkformValidation();
            //checkValidation();
            //$("#appForm").validate();
            if ($("#appForm").valid()) {
                alert("success");
                return;
            } else {
                alert("wrong");
            }
            //$('#submitAppModal').modal('show');
        });
      });
```

Comment: Since you tagged this question JavaScript, which is client-side code, show us the actual rendered JavaScript & HTML markup instead the ASP.

Comment: Also FYI, putting `.validate()` inside of the form's submit `click` handler makes no sense.  The `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the plugin on your form on page load.  Capturing the click is then automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `asp-for` try `name` attribute on input

A **'name'** attribute is required for all input elements needing validation, and the plugin will not work without this.

if you want `asp-for` for some other purpose you can keep it but you got to have a name on input for validation using the plugin mentioned

https://jsfiddle.net/206ku1yL/1/

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {  
  var checkformValidation = function () {
                $("#appForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    "TaxPreparer.FirstName": "required"
                }
                });
            }

       $('#submitApp').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                checkformValidation();
                //checkValidation();
                //$("#appForm").validate();
                if ($("#appForm").valid()) {
                    alert("success");
                    return;
                } else {
                    alert("wrong");
                }
                //$('#submitAppModal').modal('show');
            });
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<form id="appForm" asp-controller="some" asp-action="AnonymousApp" method="post">
   
    <div class="panel-body pt0 p10">
                <section class="grid grid--direction-row">
                    <!-- First Name -->
                    <div class="grid__col-4">
                        <label class="control-label">First Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                        <input name="TaxPreparer.FirstName" class="form-control" maxlength="50"/>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Middle Name -->
                    <div class="grid__col-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Middle Name</label>
                        <input name="TaxPreparer.MiddleName" class="form-control charlimit" maxlength="50"/>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Last Name -->
                    <div class="grid__col-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Last Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                        <input name="TaxPreparer.LastName" class="form-control charlimit" maxlength="50"/>
                    </div>
                </section>
   
   </div>
   <input class="btn btn-success btn-large" style="float: right; "id="submitApp" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Thanks Punith, Also, may I please know the reason for why it doesn't work with asp-for tag helper?

Comment: @KimboSlice in the documentation https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/ it mention that you have to address to name of the input for validation

Comment: but isn't asp-for is the same like name and id? asp-for = "Taxpreparer.Name" gives html => name= "Taxpreparer.Name" id="Taxpreparer_Name"

Comment: @KimboSlice, then why did you put the ASP markup in your jsFiddle instead of the actual rendered HTML markup that a browser would use?

Comment: @Sparky there was something else preventing the validation, it does work with both asp-for and name, The asp-for tag is implemented by someone else working on it. thank you.