# click function submits the form after executing

Tags: jquery, form-submit, submit-button

In the following code, on clicking go button the form should submit first then the validation should go. But the form is submitting after executing full #go.click function.

```
$('#go').click(function()  {
        $('form[name=dataExport]').submit();
         var distIdEntry = $.trim($("input[name='distID']").val());
       var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
                }
            }
        };




          var districtID =getUrlParameter('distwpid');;

          if (distIdEntry.length === 0)
          {

          }


          //if input doesn't equal our district ID
          else if (distIdEntry !== districtID)
          {

          }
          //if input = our district ID
    else if (distIdEntry === districtID)
              {
               }
          return true;         
   });//End GO function
```

Comment: Don't you want it to validate first? Why would you want to submit an invalid form?  See this question for more help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828560/jquery-validate-stop-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

Put your validation code inside of the submit function:

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    $('form[name=dataExport]').submit(function() {
        // validation code
    });
});
```

Comment: Before the `$("#go")` code, try adding an event handler to the submit code like so:

    $("form[name=dataExport]").on("submit", function() {
        // validation code
    });

    $("#go").click(function(){
        $('form[name=dataExport]').submit();
    });

Comment: I have put some alert. Conclusion is the same that $("form[name=dataExport]").on("submit", function()}); is executing with the #go.click after then only the form is submitted.